# AdWords API, updating to v201809

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

I'm stuck with updating from v201802 to v201809.
I'd prefer the binary distribution of the library by updating the dll's in my application's /bin folder.
So I downloaded the files of v24.3.0 from
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/releases

But, what confuses me totally is that there are no Google.AdWords.dll and Google.Ads.Common.dll files included in the /lib folder.
??

Shall I just keep the old versions, or... ?

What exactly are the files I need to update?

I appreciate your advice.

Armin